# Accessing S3 from Spark 2.0

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm trying to access S3 file from SparkSQL job. I already tried solutions from several posts but nothing seems to work. Maybe because my EC2 cluster runs the new Spark2.0 for Hadoop2.7.

I setup hadoop this way:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", accessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", secretKey)
```

I build an uber-jar using sbt assembly using:

```
name := "test"
version := "0.2.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" %   "1.7.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.3" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule("com.amazonaws", "aws-java-sdk"),
    ExclusionRule("commons-beanutils")
)

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0" % "provided"
```

When I submit my job to the cluster, I always got the following errors:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 172.31.7.246):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2638)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1726)    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:662)     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:446)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$3.apply(Executor.scala:476)

It seems that the driver is able to read from S3 without problem but not the workers/executors... I do not understand why my uberjar is not sufficient.

However, I tried as well without success to configure spark-submit using:

> --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3

PS: If I switch to s3n protocol, I got the following exception:

> java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n

Comment: have you using accessing s3 file from any transformation or action??

Comment: Yes, I call native C functions (through JNI) within map and reduce operation. In fact, the library containing those functions was uploaded in an S3 bucket, and it needs to be loaded by every worker nodes before running the native functions. So I add the library to the spark context using `sc.addFile(s3://pathToLibrary.so)` and then I load it using `System.load(SparkFiles.get(Library.so))`.

Comment: you can copy the aws-sdk and hadoop-aws to jars folder inside spark. (it should solve the ClassNotFoundException issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all operations of spark working on workers. and you set these configuration on master so once you can try to app configuration of s3 on mapPartition{
}

Comment: Ok you were right, I went through this issue by copying first the S3 files locally before adding it to SparkFiles.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `s3n`:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", accessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secretKey)
```

Now, regarding the exception, you need to make sure both JARs are on the *driver* and *worker* classpaths, and make sure to distribute them to the worker node if you're using Client Mode via the `--jars` flag:

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/location/to/aws-java-sdk.jar" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/location/to/hadoop-aws.jar" \
--jars /location/to/aws-java-sdk.jar,/location/to/hadoop-aws.jar \
```

Also, if you're building your uber JAR and including `aws-java-sdk` and `hadoop-aws`, no reason to use the `--packages` flag.

Comment: I already tried the same parameters for s3n protocol without success (sorry if I did not explain them). 
I know that `--packages` is not needed if I have already the dependencies in the uber JAR. I tried both methods without success. 
I'm going to try to distribute the JARs by hand and adding them to classpath and jars configuration to see if I still get the exception.

Comment: @elldekka Did you get the namespace right? With `NativeS3FileSystem`?

Comment: yes I did, the problem does not come from this part.

Comment: @elldekka Did you make sure the classpaths are set correctly?

Comment: No, I change my way to do it (See the other answer)... I don't understand why I should use set any classpath when running an uberjar...

Comment: This just resulted in the specified file system not being found